# CVC4 cannot open file in SMT2 format

Tags: file, synthesis, cvc4

I am trying to use [CVC4](https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4) to perform syntax-guided synthesis on a function. To begin, I am following [CVC4 Getting Started](https://cvc4.github.io/getting-started) and my `example.smt2` file looks like this:

```
(set-logic ALL)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert (= (+ x x) (* x 2)))
(check-sat)
```

When I run `cvc4 example.smt2` in command line in the directory, there should not be a problem based on the tutorial linked above. However, I get this error:

```
(error "Couldn't open file: example.smt2")
```

Note that this error is not the same as if the file does not exist. For example, when I run `cvc4 exampl.doesnotexist`, the following error occurs:

```
CVC4 Error:
Couldn't open file: exampl.doesnotexist
```

Which is different. I looked this up everywhere but could not find an answer. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the read-permissions on the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get this error if you don't have read-permissions on the file:

```
$ cat example.smt2
(set-logic ALL)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert (= (+ x x) (* x 2)))
(check-sat)
$ cvc4 example.smt2
sat
$ chmod u-r example.smt2
$ cvc4 example.smt2
(error "Couldn't open file: example.smt2")
$ cat example.smt2
cat: example.smt2: Permission denied
$ chmod u+r example.smt2
$ cat example.smt2
(set-logic ALL)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert (= (+ x x) (* x 2)))
(check-sat)
$ cvc4 example.smt2
sat
```

Depending on your operating system, simply allow read access and the problem should go away.